# Store values of dynamically created controls

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have to create text box dynamically on each button click and the previous values should be loaded correctly. I know by saving the value to hidden field i can achieve this. Is there any other option for achieving this. Because by increasing the number of the controls the hidden field value also increases

Comment: do not change previous value, create new text box on click and fill it and so on.

Comment: Can you share with some more information about 'previous values'? Are they from other input fields?

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be multiple solution to your problem:
1. Save your values in session on each post back.
2. Or you can save your values in single hidden field with comma separated values.

For further assistance you can email me.

Comment: Thank you I have used hidden field